# What's the phrase for assuming someone else knows that you know what YOU know that you know?

Tags: phrases

Example: Student Bob assumes he won't have to take an upcoming test. Bob knows everything that he will be tested on, and assumes Bob's teacher knows this.

Comment: _Mind reading_.

Comment: @Lawrence: Close, but not the word I was looking for. I think the second word in the phrase is "thinking"

Comment: Are you referring to the *infinite regress of mutual knowledge* where A knows that B knows that A knows that ... ?

Comment: Having a [theory of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind_in_animals), sometimes (confusingly) called *mentalism* or *mind-reading*, is the opposite, i.e. being aware that others don't always know what you know, and vice versa, as well as understanding deceit and lying.

Answer (score -1):

**Infinite regress (of mutual knowledge)**

After clarifying our use of terminology, we turn our attention to the **Mutual Knowledge Paradox** which addresses the problem of how an **infinite regression of knowledge** required for an instance of S-meaning can be achieved in finite processing time in everyday conversation. Two broad approaches to resolving the paradox are examined: (1) those accounts which assume an infinite regression, with a mechanism for inferring mutual knowledge; and (2) those accounts which do not assume an infinite regression, with a truncation heuristic for inferring shared beliefs. [Benny Lee; "Mutual knowledge, background knowledge and shared beliefs: Their roles in establishing common ground", *Journal of Pragmatics*, Vols. 33, n.1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378216699001289)